# How to perform a click on element2 when element1 is clicked in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two independent elements (not a parent-child).

Is it possible to accomplish the behavior such that StyledDropDownInputAsync is actually clicked on clicking StyledSearchInput.

```
        <StyledSearchInput/>
        <StyledDropdownInputAsync searchIcon
          className="options"
          placeholder="Search"
          loadOptions={loadOptions}
          onChange={this.handleSelection}
          cache={{}}
          filterOptions={(options) => (options)}>
        </StyledDropdownInputAsync>
```

Comment: both the component is in a wrapped in a parent component, so you can have state at the parent component and when clicking on you can do the logic there and pass that state as a prop to the other component ... I think this way you can achieve it . Can you explain more on the usecase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in a parent component, define a click state, pass the click state to `StyledDropdownInputAsync`, pass the click action to `StyledSearchInput`.

```
const ParentComp = () => {
  const [isClicked, setClick] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <StyledSearchInput onClick={() => setClick(true)}/>
      <StyledDropdownInputAsync isClicked={isClicked} {...otherProps}>
      </StyledDropdownInputAsync>
    </>
  );
};
```

This called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to implement such things,

according to documentation, `Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.`

you can read more about refs using [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) link.

for implementing such functionality, please refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-bassi-bceip) code sandbox

Comment: Since both component are in the same component you can hold a state variable and use that one, Is there any need of using ref here...